# Dynamic Navigation Sidebar Content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navigation sidebar on my site with all of the main site pages, where every page has the same links, except the current page isn't a link, so you can visually tell which page you're on, and there's no reason for a link to the current page.  Currently, I'm doing this manually, copying and pasting the list of links every time I create a new page, then replacing the link to the current page with plain text.  However, then I have to go back to all of the existing pages and add the new page.  Is there any way to create a list of links in an external file, maybe a JS script or something, that dynamically removes the link on the list item for the current page, replacing it with just text, so I can just import it in my page template and update all of the pages at the same time when I add a new page?

It's a pretty simple list of links.  For example, here's the list as it appears on the /overworld/lightworld page.

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      Overworld

      <ul>
        <li>Light World</li>

        <li><a href="/overworld/icyworld/">Icy World</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the same list on the /overworld/icyworld page:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      Overworld

      <ul>
        <li><a href="/overworld/lightworld/">Light World</a></li>

        <li>Icy World</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The list is longer than that, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple `PHP`.

Create a file called `nav.php`, for example. Put in it your menu. Then, to call this file from any other location, simply put this:

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

Then, if you want to change given link on every site, you just need to modify it once in `nav.php` file.

P.S - all of your files must have `.php` extension, otherwise it won't work.